# How to approach this integration : $\int\frac{4(x^3 - 1)}{4x^5 + 16x^3 + 4x^2 + 1} \; dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, intuition

I just made the following problem to the ways in which i can approach an integral problem.

> $$\int\dfrac{4(x^3 - 1)\;dx}{4x^5 + 16x^3 + 4x^2 + 1}$$

I created this problem, such that if it is presented in a certain way would be very easy to integrate. But I then changed the original look of the function.

Now I cant find any way to integrate this, except looking at the original expression.

**How can we easily evaluate this integral?** It isn't immediately obvious to me many times what to substitute!

Comment: indefinite integral or integral over R?

Comment: @samjoe Are you sure that this integral is equal to the original (simple) one?

Comment: @Robert Z Yes. divide by x^3, and it turns out to be similar to what piotr pointed out in the end. I want to find is there any other way to evaluate this?

Comment: Could you please tell us the original form, this may help.

Comment: @samjoe I believe that something is wrong here.
The denominator could be $x^8-8x^5+16x^2+1$.

Comment: The part of your question, "how do we have to approach an integral problem in general?" was far too broad, so I removed it. The integral itself is fine.

Comment: @6005 The question is valid, but he wants the standard techniques applied to a question for which they do not work. The integral as stated is tied up with rationality questions. He has made an algebra mistake and now boxed himself in a corner, it is not clear how someone would go about answering the question.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Hmm, indeed an odd case. As the question reads, it's just asking to evaluate that particular integral. Perhaps a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**
As Rene said, there might be an error in the question. There might be $1\over x$ instead of $1$ in the denominator. If there is no error, then ignore the solution below.

We first divide by $x^3$. Subsequently the given integral can be rewritten as: $$\int\dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{x^3}}{\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2+2^2}$$

Now put $(x+\dfrac{1}{2x^2}) = u$ and $du$ is the numerator.

Comment: Your denominator is $4x^5+16x^3+4x^2+\frac{1}{x}$, so you have probably discovered OP's mistake.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus Aha! I see! Sorry for the mistake. I'll correct it.

Comment: I mean your integral is equal $\int \dfrac{4(x^3 - 1)}{4x^5 + 16x^3 + 4x^2 + \frac{1}{x}} dx$.

Comment: OP's has clearly made some mistake, as the question as posted is not solvable ( unless he is in possession of the solution to a fifth degree equation).

Answer (score 3):

I guess experience just puts a check list into your head.

First thing I do is check if we aren't integrating $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x) + a}$. Where a is a constant.

Then, I look for standard forms. Maybe there is a $\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x) +1}$ in there?

Next step is to try factoring terms out, and repeating the process.
After that - few steps of partial integration. Are the powers getting lower? Does this feel manageable?

Last step is to plot the integrator and look for some parametrisation.